# Why is this proof about integral elements and $R$-modules true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I have the following definitions.

> Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ an extension ring. We say that $x\in S$ is integral over $R$ if there exists a monic polynomial $g\in R[X]$ such that $g(x)=0$.

Now I have the following statement:

> Let $R\subset S$ be a ring and $x\in S$. Then $x$ is integral over $R$ implies that $R[x]$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

In the lecture we did the following

> **Proof.** We know that there exists $g\in R[X]$ monic such that $g(x)=0$ with $\deg(g)=d$. Then $1,x,...,x^{d-1}$ generate $R[x]$ as an $R$-module.

But somehow I don't see why from $g(x)=0$ we can deduce that $1,x,...,x^{d-1}$ generate $R[x]$?

Could someone maybe explain this to me?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If $g(x)=0$, then $x^d=-(a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_{d-1}x^{d-1})$ can be expressed by $1,x,\ldots, x^{d-1}$, and hence also all $x^{d+k}$, so all monomials in $R[x]$.

Comment: perfect thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want a proof by induction. First of all, if you write
$$
g(X)=X^d-a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\dots+a_1X+a_0
$$
you have
$$
x^d=a_{d-1}x^{d-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0 \tag{*}
$$
Suppose that $k\ge d$ and that $x^k$ is an $R$-linear combination of $1,x,\dots,x^{d-1}$, so
$$
x^k=b_{d-1}x^{d-1}+\dots+b_1x+b_0
$$
Then
$$
x^{k+1}=b_{d-1}x^d+b_{d-2}x^{d-1}+\dots+b_1x^2+b_0x \tag{**}
$$
and you can substitute (*) in (**) to finish.